# MATCH AGAINST mysql query not working as expected

Tags: mysql

I am trying to optimize the search engine on my site. The current mySQL query that populates results works 'okay' but really isn't all that great. For example, these queries are never picked up as a search result: "A&M", "E.S.Y.", "DVS", though they are part of the database and stored in the 'name' column. Search queries like "Exist"or "Hollywood Designs" are found as expected however.

I was wondering if there is a way to fix the query below so it populates results more accurately, b/c right now it is leaving out a lot of results and isn't working as expected. I appreciate any help with this.

This is the current query i am using to populate search results:

$results = mysql_query("SELECT keywords,name FROM files WHERE MATCH (keywords,name) AGAINST ('$searchfor')") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: You may want to consider using a fulltext search server for this, instead of MySQL, as MySQL's FULLTEXT search isn't great. I recommend sphinx. http://sphinxsearch.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem relates to the word length limitation mysql has by default. e.g `A&M` is not one word, but two (the `&` is ignored). Typically this limitation (`ft_min_word_len`) is set to 3.

In this mysql manual you can see, how you can tweak the config. Set `ft_min_word_len` to one: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Important side notes:

- you have to reindex your fulltext index, otherwise your search will not change.
- If you use huge data sets, be aware that this change might decrease the speed of your fulltext queries significantly.